# cmake: Link order of external (generated) and compiled objects, and libs

Tags: cmake

I'm playing around with bare-metal x86 and I've hit a snag porting my build from straight-up makefiles to cmake.

In my makefile my objects are defined like this:

```
LINK_LIST=\
$(LDFLAGS) \
$(ARCHDIR)/crti.o \
$(ARCHDIR)/crtbegin.o \
$(KERNEL_OBJS) \
$(LIBS) \
$(ARCHDIR)/crtend.o \
$(ARCHDIR)/crtn.o \
```

crtbegin.o and crtend.o are 'generated', that is, provided by my cross-compiler (-print-file-name flag). $(LIBS) are -l flags, like -lgcc, etc. Since this is passed directly to the linker the order is as specified.

My cmake target is defines as follows:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(loader 
    "${INIT_SRC}"
    "${INIT_OBJ}"
    "${PLATFORM_SRCS}"
    "${ISA_SRCS}"
    "${GENERIC_SRCS}"
    "${FINI_OBJ}"
    "${FINI_SRC}")
```

INIT_OBJ and FINI_OBJ have EXTERNAL_OBJECT and GENERATED set to true in source file properties. Looking at the command line when running the generated makefile I see that all source files are in the order specified, but init and fini objects are last in the list.

Here is the resulting command line (edited for brevity):

`i686-elf-gcc   -nostdlib -ffreestanding -nostdinc -T linker.ld -lgcc crti.s.obj boot.s.obj loader.c.obj crtn.s.obj crtbegin.o crtend.o -o loader`

The -lgcc flag is explicit in my LINK_FLAGS, which is also something I would like to change.

So I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Why isn't cmake using the order for the two external object files, but IS using it for the compiled ones?
2. How can I tell cmake to treat these objects the same as the ones coming from my sources?
3. How could I get a complete clone of the setup I have in my Makefile (with the library flags between my object files)

I did also check out CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE as well, but it doesn't seem to have enough granularity/control over the linker params to achieve this.

I'm using cmake 3.10.2 on ubuntu.

And another (off-topic) question about cmake:

It doesn't treat .S as a standard assembly file extension. I tried adding it with `LIST(APPEND CMAKE_ASM-ATT_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS S)`, and it does add it just fine, however the files still aren't getting compiled unless I change it to .s. Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: As for additional question, `.S` extension means assembler code which is needed to be **preprocessed**. Some C compiler are able to preprocess that code and compile it. But not all ASM compilers are able to preprocess code. See more in [CMake wiki](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/languages/Assembler#supported-assembler-dialects). Please, ask a **single** question in the question post - this is how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: As for the "main" question, there is a little sence in the specific order of source/object files. It is **libraries** which should come in order. CMake has a special command for link libraries - `target_link_libraries`. All options passed to that command will come **after** object files in the command line with garantee.

Comment: 1. You are correct, the off-topic question doesn't belong in here. It wont happen again. 2. I'm aware that .S files are meant to be preprocessed, it just seems strange that cmake wouldn't handle them. Thanks for the link, I didn't come across this page when searching for the .S issue.

Comment: 3. I'm following a bunch of articles/tutorials on [osdev.org](osdev.org), specifically [this](https://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_C_Library) and [this](https://wiki.osdev.org/Meaty_Skeleton), where it says that object files must be linked in a specific order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o`, which has specific requirement about position in the link command, may be treated as a part of **toolchain**. If you decide that, then you can set the variable `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE` to reflect this specific:

```
SET(ARCHDIR "<...>")
# Object 'crtbegin.o' will be linked before all other objects and libraries.
# Object 'crtend.o' will be linked after all other objects and libraries.
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS> 
    <LINK_FLAGS>
    ${ARCHDIR}/crtbegin.o
    <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>
    ${ARCHDIR}/crtend.o")
```

This setting should be done in the toolchain file, which is passed to `cmake` with option `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN=<path/to/toolchain/file>`.

With such toolchain, in the `CMakeLists.txt` you may simply write

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(loader ${PLATFORM_SRCS} ${ISA_SRCS} ${GENERIC_SRCS})
```

---

Using `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE` variable you may also position options such as

```
-nostdlib -ffreestanding -nostdinc -T linker.ld -lgcc
```

which are very toolchain-related too.

See also this mailing: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-June/037641.html.

Comment: Thanks, the way you suggested works. One remaining issue is that INIT_SRC should be linked before INIT_OBJ, and FINI_SRC after FINI_OBJ. I guess these are also toolchain specific. Should/could I compile them explicitly in the toolchain file and add them to the CMAKE_LINK_C_EXECUTABLE?

Comment: "Should/could I compile them explicitly in the toolchain file and add them to the CMAKE_LINK_C_EXECUTABLE?" - It looks so... At least, I know no other way for place an object file **after** the libraries. Note, that you cannot use `add_executable` in the toolchain. So you need to resort to `execute_process` or `add_custom_command` with a plain command line for compile the `init_src` and `fini_src`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it when I get a chance